# Non trivial rank 2 holomorphic vector bundles in complex dimensions greater than or equal 2

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology, vector-bundles

Does every compact complex manifold of complex dimension greater than or equal two 
possess a nontrivial rank 2 holomorphic vector bundle?

Comment: Aren't complex tori Oka manifolds?

Comment: Oops, complex tori don't work: $h^{0,1}$ is always nonzero.

Comment: Consider the Calabi-Eckman manifold = $S^3 \times S^3$, I would guess that since $b_{2} = b_{4} = 0$, that there is not even non-trivial rank 2 complex bundle..?

Comment: @Nick Lindsay   But  we may still have some nontrivial holomorphic structures in the trivial complex vector bundle over the Calabi-Eckman manifold you have mentioned. Am I right?

Comment: yeah, that is true. I don't know how to rule that out.

Answer (score 4):

Some partial answer:

On non-Kahler surfaces we can give stronger version of your question and we have allways the following thorem

**Theorem**: Let $S$ be non-Kahler surfaces, For any $n > 0$ there exists a Mumford stable rank-2 vector bundle $E$ with trivial determinant, ($det(E) = \mathcal O_S$ ) and $c_2(E)=n$.

We have also the following theorem due to Banica - Le Potier

**Theorem**: If $S$ is a non-projective surface and $N$ is enough big
, then there exists rank-2 vector bundles on $S$ with $c_2(E) = N$
which are non-filtrable.

We have following theorem due to Ballico and Schwarzenberger

**Theorem**: If $S$ be a projective surface and $E$ is any topological rank-2
vector bundle with $det(E) \in Pic(X)$, then $E$ has a holomorphic
structure by applying [elementary transformations](http://www.seminariomatematico.unito.it/rendiconti/cartaceo/44-4/1.pdf) starting from the
trivial bundle.

We have Cartan-Serre theorem for construction of rank 2 vector bundles on projetive varieties.

**Theorem**: Let $X$ be a complex manifold, $L_1, L_2 ∈ Pic(X)$ are line bundles,
$Z ⊂ X$ with $codim_X(Z) = 2$. Under some cohomological conditions, the
sheaf $E$ sitting in

$$0 \to L_1 \to E \to L_2 \otimes J_Z → o$$
is locally free. Moreover, If $X$ is projective, any rank-2 holomorphic vector bundle can be constructed this way

Comment: Additional comment: Let $D$ be a smooth irreducible divisor on a smooth variety $X$. Then an element $\mu\in H^1(D,\mathcal N_{D/X}) $ defines a rank 2 vector bundle over $ D$.